# Test concurrent requests to a REST based web server

Tags: rest, testing, concurrency

How can I simulate thousands of GET and PUT requests to my REST based web server?Are there any tools available and if yes what are the tools available?

Answer (score 40):

ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

This is a great tool for testing REST APIs.

Example:

```
ab -c 100 -n 100 http://service/path/to/resource
```

In this example:

- "-c 100" means 100 concurrent requests and
- "-n 100" means 100 requests

Comment: Thank you.So this can be used to simulate data retrieval of different sizes also? Are there ways to specify file sizes?

Comment: i'm not aware about this feature(i.e. file size)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils`

Answer (score 4):

I know its an old question however I needed a simple AJAX based Script to Test Multiple Concurrent Connections. If any of you have similar requirements then you can also use like this one for your tests.

[image: Snapshot of JS Code simulating Multiple Ajax Requests]

Please take a look the [this js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/urxpjzs8/) or See attached (whichever suits you as both points to the same javascript code)

```js
var interval;
            var queue = [];
            var globalElapsedTime;
            
             function getUrl() {
                    return $.trim($("#txtAjayUrl").val());
                }
            
             $("#btnLaunchRequests").on("click", function () {
                    queue = [];
                    $("#divTimeElapsed").html("<i>calculating</i>");                    
                    globalElapsedTime = window.performance.now();
                    $("#divRequestStatus").show();
                    $("#btnLaunchRequests").prop("disabled", true);
                    var totalRequests = 50;
                    var inputValue = $("#txtNumberOfConcurrentRequests").val();
                    totalRequests = inputValue.trim();

                    $("#divTotalNumberOfProcessed").html(totalRequests.toString());
                    if (interval != null && interval != undefined) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                    interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                        $("#divNumberOfCurrentRequests").text(queue.length);
                    }, 500);

                    for (let i = 1; i <= totalRequests; i++) {
                        console.log("Loop No. " + i);
                        if (i == totalRequests) {
                            $.get(getUrl(), function (data) {
                                queue.push("1");
                                $("#btnLaunchRequests").prop("disabled", false);
                                $("#divNumberOfCurrentRequests").text(queue.length);
                                //clearInterval(interval);
                            }).always(function () {
                                $("#btnLaunchRequests").prop("disabled", false);
                                globalElapsedTime = window.performance.now() - globalElapsedTime;
                                globalElapsedTime = Math.round((globalElapsedTime / 1000) * 100) / 100;                                                                
                                console.log("%cLast Result Processed in " + globalElapsedTime + " Seconds.", "color:green");
                                $("#divTimeElapsed").text(globalElapsedTime + " seconds");
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            $.get(getUrl(), function (data) {
                                queue.push("1");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3>HTTP GET Concurrent Requests Tester</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul>
                    <li>Sample Ajax URL for concurrent request testing: <input type="text" id="txtAjayUrl" value="http://localhost:4500/Api/Home/GetCustomerDetails/36603/Test" style="width:100%"> <br><br>
                    </li>                    
                    
                    <li><input type="number" value="50" id="txtNumberOfConcurrentRequests"> <input type="button" value="Launch Concurrent Requests" id="btnLaunchRequests"> <br></li>
                            
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row" id="divRequestStatus" style="">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Total Number of Requests
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Total Number of Requests Processed
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Total Time Elapsed
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="divTotalNumberOfProcessed"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="divNumberOfCurrentRequests" style="font-weight: bolder;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="divTimeElapsed"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try jmeter, there is a third party REST plugin: http://smartrics.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/jmeter-to-test-robustness-of-system.html

Comment: After struggling with Windows 10 conflicts using Rest Commander, I tried JMeter and found it to be absolutely fine for my purposes.  Bit of overhead  learning the interface, but it's quite sensible.  I'd be over the moon if PostMan implemented concurrency, though!

Answer (score -3):

Just about any HTTP performance test tool, either commercial or open source, can be used to performance test your REST interface.

Comment: The OP was after examples.

Comment: The original poster may have been after examples, but they would all be tool specific.  REST rides on either HTTP or SMTP for transport.  So, any tool that supports these interfaces, or even a raw sockets interface, can be used to send and receive RESTful messages.   That the architectural vision is not present in one conducting the test and selecting the tool should worry whoever has asked for the test information to reduce risk in deployment.  A knowledge of architecture is a foundation skill for performance testers

Comment: GET and PUT places this architecturally in the HTTP camp as the transport.  So, looking at architecture, any HTTP based performance testing tool will do the job for exercising the interface.  Some may have other desirable features, such as monitoring, analysis capabilities, SLA reporting or even be more suited to the skills of the team.  As for me, I would get a short term license of either LoadRunner or SOASTA CloudTest

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree with everything you are saying in answer and comments, but without the list, it's just wasn't a useful answer.  The question kind of assumed the existence of such things, but requested some ideas.  Having just spent a day searching for and trialling test runners, I can see the value in a list of recommendations.  I hadn't even seen the two you've mentioned here!  Thanks.  I'll remove downvote after time period has expired.